# connect Java VisualVM to a local application

Tags: java, jmx

When i try  connect Java VisualVM to a local application via an explicit JMX connection with following cmd `java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9898 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -jar  javaws.jar` it gives an error:

> unable to access jarfile javaws.jar.

But, when i use another .jar file it works. But does not work for javaws.jar. What is the reason for this exception.

Comment: does jar file work without JMX arguments?

Answer (score 1):

may be the command is not able to identify the jar file palce.

Try with this option

> java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9898 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -jar "%JAVA_HOME%"\jre\lib\javaws.jar